# Intel wifi card 7260 stops working after a few minutes

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

My Intel 7260 wifi card stops working after a few minutes being active. A reboot makes the card work again, only to stop working after a couple of minutes.

I have already gone through every post I could on this problem, but not a single one contained a solution that worked for me.

First some background information.
I'm pretty sure the wifi card is a part of my motherboard, and it has been working perfectly for years. I switched from windows to ubuntu a few weeks ago, but the problems only started appearing a few days ago. I also recently switched from unity/gnome to i3, but the problems with the internet started before I switched to i3.

The wifi driver is iwlwifi, I have tried updating it, but it did not solve the problem. Running `sudo service network-manager restart` does not fix the problem either.

Here are some results after running some commands in the terminal:

Wifi card:

```
$ lspci | grep -i network
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
```

Linux version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ole-desktop 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also the linux version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

These commands were all ran after the wifi stopped working:

The currently connected wifi (Even though it doesn't actually work):

```
$ nmcli -t -f ssid dev wifi | cut -d\' -f2
Torpstubben2.4GHz
```

(Which is my network)

The available networks (none):

```
$ nmcli dev wifi
*  SSID                  MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

List of wireless connection stuff:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

List over internet devices:

```
$ ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:7d:12:5d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:7d:12:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:680291 (680.2 KB)  TX bytes:680291 (680.2 KB)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:fd:ce:7c:98:cc  
          inet addr:192.168.10.176  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a01:79d:3e84:4010:944f:4968:978b:63e4/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c769:2f36:f941:a360/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a01:79d:3e84:4010:94c7:c42:2d40:c59d/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44965 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:137646789 (137.6 MB)  TX bytes:5528195 (5.5 MB)
```

Trying to scan for networks (I think):

```
$ sudo iwlist scan
wlp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Input/output error

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Trying to turn the wifi off and on again:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlp5s0 down
    # no return, but it ran successfully
$ sudo ifconfig wlp5s0 up  
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

Power saving:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf 
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

This problem is irritating for obvious reason, any help towards fixing it would be greatly appreciated! Please do tell me if you need more information or if I should give the results of more commands.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I've added it

Comment: Edit the file to change it to `wifi.powersave = 2` then reboot

Comment: Alrighty, I'll report back my results.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you so much!! I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, and this seems to have done the trick! :D
If you add it as an actual answer I'll mark it as the correct one.